# Controlling access to static content using node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

So, I'm writing a web application in node.js where users can upload photos, and they can specify some access control settings on every photo (public, private, friends only).

I then check the users' session key on every request to ensure that they have access. If they do, I send them the file by opening it using fs and piping it to the response object.

However, when I benchmark this with apachebench, I get around 1500 requests per second. If I remove all the database stuff, it doesn't get much faster. By comparison, Nginx serves 17000 requests per second on the same photo.

Obviously this order-of-magnitude difference is going to be a huge cost problem if my service takes off.

Is there a better way to control access while preserving static-like performance, apart from making them all public?

Edit: realistically, the file is going to be hosted on S3, not in the filesystem. So node will be acting less as a static fileserver and more as an http proxy, which I suspect it will be much better at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an S3 [signed URL](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/amazon-s3-signed-urls).  A signed URL is a temporary URL for private files that you can send to a single user that references an S3 object.

You can also put an expiration time on a signed URL so it doesn't stick around forever.

So the flow would look like this:

1. Handle incoming request
2. look up authentication in database
3. make API call to S3 to generate signed URL
4. redirect user to S3 signed URL

---

Here's a related blog post: [Amazon S3 Signed URLs with NodeJS](http://kitcarrau.tumblr.com/post/12841485836/amazon-s3-signed-urls-with-nodejs).

Comment: Thanks. I will evaluate this option against proxying a request to s3 (and thus avoiding the latency from the redirect, which I suspect won't be acceptable). Other options always welcome!